# Variable assignment/replacement issues

Tags: replacement, variable-definitions, assignment, variable

I have three questions about variable assignment.

```
Module[{z},
z = y;
p'[y] /. p -> Function[y, Evaluate[z]]]
```

When I run the above code, it outputs 0.

1) If I run the same code outside the `Module`, it gives me 1. Why isn't the local `z` treated like the global case (which I can understand)?

2) If I remove the call to `Evaluate` (and run without the module), it again gives me 0. When does Mathematica replace the symbol `z` with `y`, the definition I gave, and when not?

It's especially confusing that I have to be global and evaluate, when other times the replacement seems even more aggressive:

```
fn[x_] := Module[{}, x = 1; x]
fn[2]
```

This gives me an error, `Cannot assign to raw object 2`, because it's gone and replaced the symbol `x` with the value I passed, no evaluate, no global, nothing.

3) What's the difference in this case?

This seems to come up again and again in different ways, and always comes back to the same unclear replacement/assignment rules. It just ends up being complete guesswork for me. Why do the assignment rules seem so much more arbitrary and less clear than in other languages?

Comment: There's renaming happening behind the scenes, resulting in `Function[y$, y]`, whose derivative is indeed 0. Use `TracePrint[]` to see what's happening in detail. Also, try `Module[{z}, z = y; p'[y] /. p -> Function[Evaluate[y], Evaluate[z]]]`.